# Using mouse button as part of a keyboard shortcut?

Tags: keyboard, workspaces, gnome-shell, mouse-scroll, workspace-switcher

In Ubuntu 16.04 (Unity), I have a shortcut set to change workspaces by holding <kbd>Super</kbd>+MouseWheelUp or <kbd>Super</kbd>+MouseWheelDown.  I'm trying to set up something similar on GNOME with Ubuntu 17.10.  However, I can't find a way using Settings, GNOME Tweaks, or the DConf editor to add in mouse buttons as part of keyboard shortcuts.  Can anyone point me in the right direction?

My goal:

<kbd>Super</kbd>+MouseWheelUp bound to Workspace Up

<kbd>Super</kbd>+MouseWheelDown bound to Workspace Down

Answer (score 3):

That combination is there in GNOME by default, the only thing different is you'll have to release <kbd>super</kbd> before start scrolling.

So here the workflow is: press *and release* <kbd>super</kbd>, then MouseWheelUp to go to the workspace above or MouseWheelDown to go to the workspace below.

Comment: Thanks, I'm aware of this shortcut.  But I'm more curious how to bind mouse buttons as part of keyboard shortcuts in general.